# Can print but not return html table: "TypeError: ResultSet object is not an iterator"

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, mechanize-python

Python newbie here. Python 2.7 with beautifulsoup 3.2.1.

I'm trying to scrape a table from a simple page. I can easily get it to print, but I can't get it to return to my view function.

The following works:

```
@app.route('/process')
def process():

   queryURL = 'http://example.com'

   br.open(queryURL)

   html = br.response().read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
   table = soup.find("table")
   print table

   return 'All good'
```

I can also `return html` successfully. But when I try to `return table` instead of `return 'All good'` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ResultSet object is not an iterator
```

I also tried:

```
br.open(queryURL)

html = br.response().read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table")
out = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    colvals = [col.text for col in row.findAll('td')]
    out.append('\t'.join(colvals))

return table
```

With no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to return an object, you're not actually getting the text of the object so `return table.text` should be what you are looking for. Full modified code:

```
def process():

   queryURL = 'http://example.com'

   br.open(queryURL)

   html = br.response().read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
   table = soup.find("table")
   return table.text
```

EDIT:

Since I understand now that you want the HTML code that forms the site instead of the values, you can do something like this example I made:

```
import urllib

url = urllib.urlopen('http://www.xpn.org/events/concert-calendar')
htmldata = url.readlines()
url.close()

for tag in htmldata:
    if '<th' in tag:
        print tag
    if '<tr' in tag:
        print tag
    if '<thead' in tag:
        print tag
    if '<tbody' in tag:
        print tag
    if '<td' in tag:
        print tag
```

You can't do this with BeautifulSoup (at least not to my knowledge) is because BeautifulSoup is more for parsing or printing the HTML in a nice looking manner. You can just do what I did and have a for loop go through the HTML code and if a tag is in the line, then print it.

If you want to store the output in a list to use later, you would do something like:

```
htmlCodeList = []
for tag in htmldata:
        if '<th' in tag:
            htmlCodeList.append(tag)
        if '<tr' in tag:
            htmlCodeList.append(tag)
        if '<thead' in tag:
            htmlCodeList.append(tag)
        if '<tbody' in tag:
            htmlCodeList.append(tag)
        if '<td' in tag:
            htmlCodeList.append(tag)
```

This save the HTML line in a new element of the list. so `<td>` would be index 0 the next set of tags would be index 1, etc.

Comment: Thanks! That worked but then it's only returning the text of the table and I'm losing the html tags. My end goal is to have that html table displayed as an html table on my view. Thoughts?

Comment: You want python to print out the table as it appears on the webpage? Is that what you're getting at?

Comment: Could you give me the html code or site and expand upon what you want to do please? @Bnjii

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yes, I want to reproduce the table as it appears on the website. Basically the page I'm scraping has a basic table with 5 columns and ~50 rows. Code is pretty classic:
<table><tbody><tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td></tr>...
I want to copy that html code and have my view return this html code. I'm actually calling my /process page from an ajax call and injecting the result of /process into a div.

Comment: And for more context, the app would be something basic with one button "Get results for Country A" that scrapes the table and displays it under the button. Makes sense?

Comment: Yup edited the question, hope its more what you are looking for @Bnjii

Comment: Thanks @heinst very helpful! Since I want the whole table would I just do something like out = [] and append all tags to it as it loops through them?
And the content of each cell would also be copied correct?
Could I just do:

if '<table' in tag:
        out = tag
return tag
?

Answer (score 0):

After @Heinst pointed out that I was trying to return an Object and not a string, I also found a more elegant solution to convert the BeautifulSoup Object into a string and return it:

```
return str(table)
```